# Telling Composer the location of a package

Tags: php

In my Laravel application I am trying to install a package that depends on the Imagick PHP extension. The error is below:

`spatie/pdf-to-image 1.8.2 requires ext-imagick * -> the requested PHP extension imagick is missing from your system.`

However 1&1 explicitly states that this is already installed under `/usr/bin/convert` according to the following link:

https://www.ionos.co.uk/help/hosting/using-php-for-web-projects/using-imagemagick/

Is there a way to tell the `composer.phar` within my project thaat the package exists elsewhere?

Comment: How are you trying add imagic?

Comment: I was intending to build the module in a folder I have access to, and link to that in my composer.phar

Comment: Maybe you need install imagick via pecl. For example pecl install imagick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible answer here:

[Link](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md)

As a package consumer you can set or override the install path for a package that requires composer/installers by configuring the installer-paths extra. A useful example would be for a Drupal multisite setup where the package should be installed into your sites subdirectory. Here we are overriding the install path for a module that uses composer/installers:

```
{
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "sites/example.com/modules/{$name}": ["vendor/package"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was installing via brew (on mac) and had problems.

`$ pecl install imagick` did it for me

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu (and other linux distros with apt), the command to install this extension is

`sudo apt install php-imagick`